# I didn't think something else vs. anything else

Tags: word-choice

I asked my friend what he's doing, and he answered that he's resting. I responded "I didn't think something else", meaning I predicted it, and he responded that he thinks it should be "I didn't think anything else".

Since both of us are not native English speakers, I'd like to know if there's something wrong with "I didn't think something else" in this context?

Comment: Native speakers don't bother with either saying, actually. They'd be more likely to say, "Called it," "Thought as much," or "I thought so."

Comment: As a US English speaker, I find "I didn't think **anything** else" is more fluent.  "something else" sounds like you had a particular something else in mind, but you actually did not have *any* other thing in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither "something else" nor "anything else" is particularly idiomatic.  "Anything else" is a little better, but I'd have said:

> I didn't think you were doing anything else.

However, there is an expression that fits well here:

> I thought so. / I thought as much.

Comment: Please, add the other options from the comments. They seem like good alternatives.

Comment: "Called it" doesn't work in this context for me.  That means "I correctly predicted it"